# Android developer phone 1 downgrade firmware

Tags: android, version, firmware, downgrade

I am trying to downgrade Android developer phone 1's firmware version from 1.6. to 1.5 by following [this](http://developer.htc.com/adp.html) link...

http://developer.htc.com/adp.html

Here I have completed till steps #7 of **Update the Device Radio Firmware**. while in steps 8,

It start to load update.zip file.
It analyze the update.zip file. and at last it shows that **update Aborted**

I have followed exact all steps mentioned in that list.

Insight will be appreciated.

-Dhaiwat

Answer (score 1):

Please verify that you have:

1) Verified the checksum of your update.zip with the HTC ADP website checksum list.

2) You waited after uploading the update.zip file to the SD card as mentioned in the Troubleshooting section.

It almost sounds like a problem with not waiting for the upload of the file to complete. Alternatively it could also be a bad SD card.